# If condition in mysql select query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables like user, question_list and private_list.
I am listing questions created by users on my home page. User can create some question private. So if another user is in private_list table he can see private question of another user.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*,
                B.*
                FROM (
                user AS A
                INNER JOIN question_list AS B ON B.user_id = A.id
                )
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I am not getting how to add if condition, if logged in user id in private_list he can able to see another user private question. I hope some one help me in this issue. My tables structure is as following...

USER:

```
 id(int AI) 
 name(varchar)
 created_at(datetime)
```

question_list

```
id(int AI)
user_id(int)
question(varchar)
is_private(tinyint)
created_at(datetime)
```

private_list

```
id(int AI)
user_id(int)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your tables' structure.

Comment: Why not have one list ?

Comment: i have updated my question with tables structure.

Comment: I've removed references to PHP. Question tags should describe your *question*, not your *project*.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got the solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*,
                B.*
                FROM (
                user AS A
                INNER JOIN question_list AS B ON B.user_id = A.id
                )
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM private_list C WHERE C.user_id = A.id AND C.user_id = B.user_id) OR B.is_private = 0 ORDER BY created_at DESC
```